# how to spawn a new Isolate in dart?

Tags: dart, dart-isolates

Is something going on wth Dart isolates at present? looking at a few past stackoverflow questions most people looked to be using `spawnIsolate` or `spawnFunction` to start a new isolate running, but those methods don't appear to exist any more, nor is there an obvious replacement for them in the current isolate library. Also when following links people have put in previous stackoverflow questions about isolates they seem to have been removed from the official documentation [such as](https://www.dartlang.org/docs/dart-up-and-running/contents/ch03.html#ch03-keeping-the-root-isolate-alive). How do you start up an isolate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote a small example on how to spawn isolates at http://www.roberthartung.de/spawning-isolates-in-dart/ . Does this help you?

Comment: I cant believe I didnt see the static methods, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

At the bottom of the page you linked is this link [dart:isolate library](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/dartdoc-viewer/dart%3aisolate)
I think this isolates are still work in progress.

I think some interesting details can be found in the discussions in the Google group [Dart Misc](https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/forum/#!forum/misc) or [Dart Web Development](https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/forum/#!forum/web) and in the issues at [dartbug.com](http://dartbug.com)

Where do you want to spawn isolates anyway, server or client?

Comment: both, I saw the link to the api docs but from those docs it doesnt seem apparent how you would spawn an isolate, there isnt a global method to do that

Comment: also the link on the isolate api page [dart:isolate - Concurrency with Isolates](https://www.dartlang.org/docs/dart-up-and-running/contents/ch03.html#ch03-dartisolate---concurrency-with-isolates) takes you back to the language tour page but the section its referring to seems to have gone.

Comment: The Isolate class has a spawn and a spawnUri static method https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/dartdoc-viewer/dart-isolate.Isolate#id_spawn. This link doesn't really work. Got to the page and click on `static functions`.

You didn't answer if it is for client or server.